# JDBC batch select returns multiple ResultSets

Tags: jdbc

A minor issue but I was wondering whether someone knows why I get the following behavior. I have a large select statement with a UNION directive. I need to call this statement for a list of inputs. Thus:

```
Connection connection = createConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(dbLoadOneQuery, TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

for (Integer param : params) {
    statement.setInt(1, param);
    statement.setInt(2, param);
    statement.addBatch();
}
statement.execute();

do {
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
    // snip
} while (statement.getMoreResults());
```

Now, I'm aware I could have done this a number of ways. Whether there is a better way is not the question. Rather, I would like to know why my results are coming in bunches? I need to read 3-4 separate ResultSets from my statement. They don't correspond to the unions, they are not of equal size, and the data is not group in any particular form.

My guess it's a driver specific thing, but I couldn't find the JDBC specification that allowed for this behavior. The driver is `com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver` from library jconn4.

```
jConnect (TM) for JDBC(TM)/7.07 GA(Build 26666)/P/EBF19485/JDK 1.6.0/jdbcmain/Wed Aug 31 03:14:04 PDT 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not executing a UNION query, it is batching *n* **separate** queries (that is `dbLoadOneQuery` with *n* different combinations of parameters), and executing them in one go, then retrieving the *n* individual ResultSet (one for each query).

If you want `UNION`s, then actually execute a `UNION` query.

Based on your query that would be something like:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append(dbLoadOneQuery);
int queryCount = params.size();
// If we have more than one parameter add a UNION clause:
while (queryCount-- > 1) {
   query.append(" UNION ").append(dbLoadOneQuery);
}
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
int paramIdx = 1;
for (Integer param : params) {
   statement.setInt(paramIdx++, param);
   statement.setInt(paramIdx++, param);
}
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: The query contained in the variable "dbLoadOneQuery" is a UNION containing query. Yes, it is batching n different calls, but does not return n results.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Each batched query will have its own resultset, which will have zero or more results. That is expected. I guess your expectations on the results of the query don't match the actual output.